# Access violation when unloading injected DLL via CreateRemoteThread

Tags: c++, windows, access-violation, dll-injection

I'm trying to cleanly inject DLL into foreground window's process, call simple function from this DLL and then cleanly unload the DLL. My injection code:

```
HWND fgwnd = GetForegroundWindow();

DWORD cur_thread = GetCurrentThreadId();
DWORD fg_pid = 0;
DWORD fg_thread = GetWindowThreadProcessId(fgwnd, &fg_pid);
BOOL res = 0;


const char* inj_path = "C:\\Users\\pc\\source\\repos\\hothook\\x64\\Debug\\fground_injector.dll";
// Get process handle to victim
HANDLE victim = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, fg_pid);

// Find exact adress of LoadLibraryA function from text space of kernel32.dll loaded by the OS
// and used by victim
PVOID llib = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
PVOID flib = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll"), "FreeLibrary");

// Allocate memory inside victim's address space
LPVOID inj_path_victim = (LPVOID)VirtualAllocEx(victim, NULL, strlen(inj_path)+1,
MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

// Write inject dll's adress into victim
SIZE_T written;
res = WriteProcessMemory(victim, inj_path_victim, inj_path, strlen(inj_path)+1, &written);

// Finally, inject DLL into victim!
// Spawn thread in remote process ================================================================
HANDLE inj_llib_thread = CreateRemoteThread(
/*I*/   victim,                             // Handle to process where thread will be created
/*I*/   NULL,                               // SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES for new thread
/*I*/   0,                                  // Initial stacks size, bytes. 0 -> default size
/*I*/   (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)llib,       // User defined callback LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE
/*I*/   inj_path_victim,                    // Ptr to variable to be sent as func parameter
/*I*/   0,                                  // Creation control flags. 0 -> immediate start
/*O|O*/ NULL);                              // Ptr to variable that recieves thread ID
// ===============================================================================================

// CANNOT WAIT FOR THREAD IN OTHER PROCESS.... OR CAN I?! I CAN!
// Wait for DLL to get properly injected into victim
res = WaitForSingleObject(inj_llib_thread, INFINITE);
// Get executable base address of the loaded DLL
DWORD llib_exit;
res = GetExitCodeThread(inj_llib_thread, &llib_exit);

// Free previously allocated remote memory
res = VirtualFreeEx(victim, inj_path_victim, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

// Call injected DLL's function
HMODULE fg_inj = LoadLibraryA(inj_path);
PVOID inj_t_proc = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(fg_inj, "injectThread");
PVOID ulib = NULL;
// Spawn thread in remote process ================================================================
HANDLE inj_thread = CreateRemoteThread(
/*I*/   victim,                             // Handle to process where thread will be created
/*I*/   NULL,                               // SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES for new thread
/*I*/   0,                                  // Initial stacks size, bytes. 0 -> default size
/*I*/   (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)inj_t_proc, // User defined callback LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE
/*I*/   NULL,                               // Ptr to variable to be sent as func parameter
/*I*/   0,                                  // Creation control flags. 0 -> immediate start
/*O|O*/ NULL);                              // Ptr to variable that recieves thread ID
// ===============================================================================================

// Wait before injected DLL's thread finishes before extraction
res = WaitForSingleObject(inj_thread, INFINITE);

// Extract injected DLL from victim
// Spawn thread in remote process ================================================================
HANDLE inj_flib_thread = CreateRemoteThread(
/*I*/   victim,                             // Handle to process where thread will be created
/*I*/   NULL,                               // SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES for new thread
/*I*/   0,                                  // Initial stacks size, bytes. 0 -> default size
/*I*/   (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)flib,       // User defined callback LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE
/*I*/   (LPVOID)llib_exit,                  // Ptr to variable to be sent as func parameter
/*I*/   0,                                  // Creation control flags. 0 -> immediate start
/*O|O*/ NULL);                              // Ptr to variable that recieves thread ID
// ===============================================================================================

// Wait untill injected DLL is fully extracted from the victim
res = WaitForSingleObject(inj_flib_thread, INFINITE);
DWORD flib_exit;
res = GetExitCodeThread(inj_flib_thread, &flib_exit);

// Extract injection DLL from host
FreeLibrary(fg_inj);
// ^^^ This actually does not unload DLL from host app, even if I call it 100 times in a loop...

// Clean up by closing all utilised handles
CloseHandle(victim);
CloseHandle(inj_llib_thread);
CloseHandle(inj_thread);
CloseHandle(inj_flib_thread);
```

My injection DLL is truly bare-bones:

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hm,
                      DWORD call_reas,
                      LPVOID reserved)
{
    switch(call_reas)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    {
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hm);
        // I thought that threads calling DllMain with case 2-3 cause crash
        // But no, same crash with or without this call
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

DWORD injectThread(LPVOID p)
{
    //AllowSetForegroundWindow(ASFW_ANY);
    // This is what it originally suppose to do
    // Let the host "steal" foreground window status from victim
    // But even commenting this out results in the same crash

    return 0;
}
```

The crash happens after I create `FreeLibrary` remote thread to unload injected DLL. This is as much crash details as I could get, as it happens in the system kernel it seems:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE598C7170 in maudswch.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00007FFE598C7170.

00007ffe598c7170()
kernel32.dll!00007ffe9ac47034()
ntdll.dll!00007ffe9c682651()

Not Flagged     50864   0   Main Thread Main Thread win32u.dll!00007ffe99e51104
Not Flagged     47548   0   Worker Thread   ntdll.dll thread    ntdll.dll!00007ffe9c6d0794
Not Flagged     41096   0   Worker Thread   ntdll.dll thread    ntdll.dll!00007ffe9c6d0794
Not Flagged     43456   0   Worker Thread   ntdll.dll thread    ntdll.dll!00007ffe9c6d0794
Not Flagged >   29820   0   Worker Thread   Win64 Thread    00007ffe598c7170
```

I tested this on many "victims". CMD, Notepad, my other custom GUI program. The result is the same. DLL gets successfully injected, DLL function gets executed, but when unloading it crashes "victim". One more detail, is that `FreeLibrary` remote thread takes quite long time to finish, about 1.5 seconds sometimes even 7 seconds!

I'm trying to solve this puzzle for days now, I searched all the Internet, but all other similar cases seems to be non-related... And at this point I have no idea what is going on and how to fix this. Of course, I can just bite the bullet and never try to unload my injected DLL, after all it works. But I don't want to leave useless DLLs in other processes after it finished it's job.

Edit:
Some debug prints. As you can see, `hm:` and `func addr:` is outputted in `DllMain` `PROCESS_ATTACH`. As you can see, I'm lucky to have base DLL address and function address to be exactly the same in host and victim processes. However, passing full base address to `FreeLibrary` external thread results in exactly the same crash, so truncated base address was not the real reason behind the crash...

[image]

Comment: You'd need to use [`FreeLibraryAndExitThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-freelibraryandexitthread) from within your DLL.

Comment: I already tried that before and it results in the same crash. That's why I figured out I need to free DLL from code external to DLL itself, but alas...

Comment: Well Remy's answer covers much of the other issues... you're corrupting quite a few things in the process of what you're doing.

Comment: @Mgetz Well, maybe that was different crash related to the fact that I couldn't synchronise with externally created threads from inside the DLL. And make sure that they are finished before it tries to unload itself.

Comment: @Mgetz It seems that I created a perfect "virus" for myself =\

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer it would help if you showed the code that tried to use `FreeLibraryAndExitThread()`. Maybe you just didn't use it correctly. We don't know, we can't see your code for it. Having `CreateRemoteThread()` call an exported function that then calls `FreeLibraryAndExitThread()` on the handle provided to `DllMain()` would be easier and safer than trying to call `FreeLibrary()` via `CreateRemoteThread()`

Comment: [What is the point of FreeLibraryAndExitThread?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131105-00/?p=2733)

Answer (score 2):

Using `GetExitCodeThread()` to retrieve the `HMODULE` returned by `LoadLibraryA()` in the target process will work only if the victim is a 32bit process.  Otherwise, the `HMODULE` will be too large to fit in the remote thread's exit code, so you will have to use a different mechanism to get the DLL's base address in the target process, such as using `EnumProcessModules()`+`GetModuleFileNameEx()` or `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`+`Module32(First|Next)()`, or even injecting stub code that calls `LoadLibraryA()` and saves the `HMODULE` into a variable that the injector allocates and can read from via `ReadProcessMemory()`.

More importantly, the way you are calling the DLL's `injectThread()` function in the target process is wrong.  You are using `LoadLibraryA()`+`GetProcAddress()` to get a pointer to the `injectThread()` function within the *injector's* process, and then you are **assuming** that the function is located at the same address in the *target* process. But the DLL in the target process may have been loaded at a *different* base address than the DLL in the injector process (especially in light of technologies like [ALSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), DLL rebasing, etc).

The correct solution is to get the *offset* of the `injectThread()` function within the DLL (which the injector can calculate by subtracting its DLL's base address from the function's address), and then add that offset to the base address of the DLL in the *target* process.

Also, make sure your `injectThread()` function has the correct signature that `CreateRemoteThread()` is expecting. What you showed is missing a calling convention specified, so it will use whatever the compiler's default convention is, which is usually `__cdecl`. But `CreateRemoteThread()` requires `__stdcall` instead.

Comment: Wow, how It didn't occur to me... I only recently found examples online that used `GetExitCodeThread` method (before I was trying to unload DLL from itself). But it was probably some legacy code from 32-bit era...

Comment: `and then you are assuming that the function is located at the same address in the target process. But the DLL in the target process may have been loaded at a different base address than the DLL in the injector process.` Wait, but all DLL's code are loaded in the same location by OS. Each process just gets the copy of non-sharable global variables for each DLL. That's why I can get address of function from `kernel32` and it will be the same for any process in the system (well maybe desktop). Same with any custom DLL. There is no point for OS to load code for each process separately.

Comment: "*I only recently found examples online that used `GetExitCodeThread` method*" - DLL injection is a bit more complicated when the target process is 64bit.

Comment: "*Wait, but all DLL's code are loaded in the same location by OS*" - no, they are not. **System DLLs** are typically loaded at the same address across multiple processes (that is certainly true for `kernel32.dll`, for instance), but **User DLLs** certainly are NOT guaranteed to be loaded at the same address in multiple processes. If 2 DLLs in a process try to load at the same address, the OS will simply move the latter one to another location.

Comment: `EXP DWORD CALLBACK injectThread(LPVOID p);` I declared function in header like this, I just didn't include `CALLBACK` in definition. Is this a problem or it can be omitted in definition?

Comment: @RemyLebeau IIRC high security processes can get a different base address for system DLLs. They trade memory for security.

Comment: _but User DLLs certainly are NOT guaranteed to be loaded at the same address in multiple processes._ Strange discrimination by the OS...

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer "*Strange discrimination by the OS*" - not really, when you take into account DLLs that the OS needs to load first in order for the process to run correctly. So it makes sense for those to be loaded at common addresses. But user DLLs don't generally require that

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer [ALSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) is pretty standard these days?

Comment: @RemyLebeau _If 2 DLLs in a process try to load at the same address, the OS will simply move the latter one to another location_ OK, but, I mean, internally DLL's .text segment should be loaded only ONCE for every DLL and put into one actual physical memory block in RAM, for example. But what you mean is, that OS can then MAP this .text module to different VIRTUAL addresses in different processes that load same DLL, right?

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer Also worth noting if this is on modern windows 10 or 11 you're likely running into Control Flow Guard at some point crashing things. It's designed to make doing exactly this hard

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer don't assume that, for security reasons a DLL can be loaded into a non-shared page if necessary. That sort of thing is extremely common for anti-malware services which actually have protection against injection. Just to make sure that someone can't detour them via another app.

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer Each process will have its own copy of the DLL's image within its own address space, and the DLL's executable code will be accessible relative to the DLL's base address in each process. Even if the `.text` segment were being shared in physical RAM, that is an implementation detail of how the OS manages the DLL. If someone were to try to write to the `.text` segment (ie, to patch code), the segment will first be copied into the writer's process. So, there is still no guarantee of a single memory address you can use to point at the DLL's executable code in multiple processes.

Comment: @Mgetz _Microsoft's Windows Vista (released January 2007) and later have ASLR enabled only for executables and dynamic link libraries that are specifically linked to be ASLR-enabled. For compatibility, it is not enabled by default for other applications_

Comment: Check out my edit to the question. Seems that truncated base address was not the reason for the crash. OFC I can send base address using shared DLL memory and use offset for the function to make it 100% fool-proof, but this will not solve The Crash at unloading. It just doesn't make any sense at all. I'm passing all the correct info and using legit API function to Free the library.....

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer yes, and that's the default setting for the compiler. So it's the common case not the uncommon case