# How to prevent DLL from loading other standard DLLs?

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I was experimenting with DLL injection via `CreateRemoteThread()` (see my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72943819/) for details). I injected it into `CMD.exe` process (note, not the `conhost.exe` process). The thing is, I noticed that it actually loads 8 other Windows DLLs along with it. It loads them even if I never use any functions from those DLLs.

Now I wonder, is there a way to prevent this? My only guess for now is to not include `<windows.h>`, then copy definitions for most macros and load libraries that are actually needed via calls to `LoadLibrary()`. Yet, I guess, it's not the most elegant solution.

Maybe there is some well established method of preventing standard satellite DLL loads?

[image]

Comment: You might not have used them, but something you called might have.

Comment: *even if I never use any functions from those DLLs.* - this is not true. you **used** it. stop use it - and will be no additional dlls loaded. at first - stop use crt - visible that you use it.

Comment: a big part of your issue is that your injector is a debug build.  So instead of calling functions in ucrtbase.dll which the application was already using, it had to load ucrtbased.dll which is the debug version.  And vcruntime140d.dll is also a debug version

Answer (score 0):

An option for cases where you only occasionally rely on a particular library is to treat it as delay-loaded.

In Visual Studio, this setting is found in the project properties window under Linker -> Input.

So, for example, if you expect to only sometimes call something from user32.dll you could add "user32.dll" to the Delay Loaded DLLs line (note that this does take .dll not .lib as for input libraries).